# Stop HTTP call and return an error using a chain of handlers; is it possible?

Tags: go, handler, middleware

Using the below code (taken from https://gist.github.com/miku/293f253b706c4de1b75c):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Payload struct {
    Name     string
    Location string
}

func readSecond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("entering readSecond")

    // r.Body is a io.ReadCloser, that's all we know
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // closing a NopCloser won't hurt anybody
    defer r.Body.Close()

    log.Printf("request body: %s", string(b))
}

func readFirst(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("entering readFirst")

    // temporary buffer
    b := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))

    // TeeReader returns a Reader that writes to b what it reads from r.Body.
    reader := io.TeeReader(r.Body, b)

    // some business logic
    var payload Payload
    if err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&payload); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // we are done with body
    defer r.Body.Close()

    log.Printf("deserialized payload from body: %v", payload)

    // NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the provided Reader r.
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(b)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    readFirst(w, r)
    readSecond(w, r)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

**Is there a way to prevent** `readSecond()` (the second handler) from being run?

Example:

If `payload == ""` I wanna quit the HTTP call and return an error.

**Is there a way to do it with this code?**

I know I can do it with nested middleware. But what with handlers like this?

Comment: Some changes would have to be made in order to change the behavior, so when you say "with this code", what sort of changes are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @Adrian the minimum possible?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't just return an error from `readFirst`? Neither of your `readX` functions needs to fulfill the `HandlerFunc` type.

Comment: @kingkupps, Do you mean an error so I can check it after `readFirst()`?

Comment: Yes! I'm asking why not make the signature `func readFirst(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error` then just check the returned error or lack thereof one.

Answer (score 1):

Using method and receiver helps have more control on errors.
You can't return error regularly in http's handlers.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Payload struct {
    Name     string
    Location string
}

type Handle struct {
    err error
}

func (h *Handle) readSecond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("entering readSecond")

    // r.Body is a io.ReadCloser, that's all we know
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // closing a NopCloser won't hurt anybody
    defer r.Body.Close()

    log.Printf("request body: %s", string(b))
}

func (h *Handle) readFirst(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("entering readFirst")
    h.err = nil

    // temporary buffer
    b := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))

    // TeeReader returns a Reader that writes to b what it reads from r.Body.
    reader := io.TeeReader(r.Body, b)

    // some business logic
    var payload Payload
    if err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&payload); err != nil {
        // log.Fatal("read first", err)
        h.err = err
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }

    // we are done with body
    defer r.Body.Close()

    log.Printf("deserialized payload from body: %v", payload)

    // NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the provided Reader r.
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(b)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var handle Handle
    handle.readFirst(w, r)
    if handle.err == nil {
        handle.readSecond(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```